# How can i put correctly the path of some variables in php?

Tags: php, ubuntu

i have a problem when i ran a php platform in windows, the paths with this estructure wokrs fine.

```
$this->logo = "http://localhost:8080/software/librerias/logo.png";
```

I just concatenate the variable like this that goes in a echo.

```
<li><img src='".$this->logo."' width='70' height='45' style='padding-right: 20px;'/></li>
```

But when i run it on ubuntu, the path and the names is the same but the image just dont charge, like all the other paths that i have.

I have already check things like the ip and the paths.

Thanks all of you!

Comment: It would be better to `$this->logo = "software/librerias/logo.png";` then the protocol will use whatever was used to load the page and the port etc etc and then regardless the images will be found assuming the same directory structure is used on all servers

Comment: Is your ubuntu server running on the standard port 80 by any chance

Comment: Hi alejandro, can you open this url in the Ubuntu  machine using the browser, and see if the image loads correctly ? 
 http://localhost:8080/software/librerias/logo.png

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe you meant `$this->logo = "/software/librerias/logo.png";` 
if the link does not start with '/' the reference to the resource is not absolute but relative to the current page

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, i already try it, the only way it works its not using the variable, coding like this: <li><img src='/software/librerias/logo.png' width='70' height='45' style='padding-right: 20px;'/></li> but i need to use the variable for future changes.

Comment: @Christian yes it loads the png.

Comment: Im givining the variable correctly but when i check in the browser it shows the value of scr empty,

 El atributo 'src' del elemento está vacío. 

<li><img src='' width='70' height='45' style='padding-right: 20px;'/></li>

Comment: Hi Alejandro, if the src is empty. Can you try to echo the value of the $this->logo  somewhere else outside of the img tag (just to see if you can see any value).  Finally, can you verify that the name of your variables are all in lowercase?

Comment: @Christian Yes i already check the names, here is the problem: i echo this  <li><img src='/software/librerias/logo.png' width='70' height='45' style='padding-right: 20px;'/></li> and it works but if i  echo this  <li><img src='".$this->logo."' width='70' height='45' style='padding-right: 20px;'/></li> it doesnt work.